# Как сделать таймер python (для скрипта)

Tags: python, время, клавиатура, таймер, мышь

Нужно сделать так чтобы задавался вопрос по типу - "Сколько секунд будет работать скрипт : тут значение в секундах " Потом, запускался таймер, и пока он идет - скрипт начинает работать, когда таймер заканчивается - скрипт выключается, и все по новой.
Заранее спасибо
Вот скрипт :

```
import keyboard
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from offset import *

mouse = Controller()

while True:
    keyboard.wait("space")
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.press("d")
        mousde.click(Button.left)
        if keyboard.is_pressed("F6"):
            break
```

Comment: Запрашиваете количество секунд, добавляете их к текущему времени, получили ожидаемое время завершения. Цикл делаете не True, а пока текущее время меньше требуемого времени завершения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример простейшего таймера на python:

переменная `timer` это количество секунд таймера

```
import time

timer = 30
for k in range(timer):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(timer)
    timer -= 1
    if timer == 0:
        break
```